# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input Promise.then (async) - React

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I am trying to display the values from my get request to the client-side using fetch. However, I am getting this syntax error:

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I know the issue is due to it not returning JSON object however I have created a JSON object for it to be received from my flask route. So I am not too sure what is causing this error.

App.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.route('/api', methods=['GET','POST'])
def api():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        email = request.form['email']
        occupation = request.form['occupation']
        print('Username: ' + username + ' Email: ' + email + ' occupation: ' + occupation) 
        print('Json ', (jsonify(username)))
        return {"username" : username} 
    else:
        return {"username" : username}
```

App.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Form from './components/Form'
import './App.css';


function App() {
  const [initialData, setInitialData] = useState ([{}])

  useEffect(()=> {

    fetch('/api').then(
      response => response.json()
    ).then(data => console.log(data))
  });





  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Content-Type and Accept headers to your fetch, example as below.

```
fetch('/api', {
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
       }).then(
      response => response.json()
    ).then(data => console.log(data))
```